# With http2, does number of XHRs have any effect on performance if overall data size is the same?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http2

As far as I know, HTTP/2 no longer uses separate TCP connections for every request, which is the main performance-booster of the protocol.

Does that mean it doesn't matter whether I use 10 XHRs with 10kB of content each or one XHR with 100kB and then split the parts client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A precise answer would require a benchmark for your specific case.

In more general terms, from the client point of view, if you can make the 10 XHR at the same time (for example, in a tight loop), then what happens is that those 10 requests will leave the client more or less at the same time, incur in the latency between the client and the server, be processed on the server (more or less in parallel depending on the server architecture), so the result could be similar of a single XHR - although I would expect the single request to be more efficient.

From the server point of view, however, things may be different.
If you multiply by 10 what could have been done with a single request, now your server sees a 10x increase in request rate.
Reading from the network, request parsing and request dispatching are all activities that are heavily optimized in servers, but they do have a cost, and a 10x increase in that cost may be noticeable.

And that 10x increase in request rate to the server may impact the database as well, the filesystem, etc. so there may be ripple effects that can only be noticed by actually performing the benchmark.

Other things that you have to weigh are the amount of work that you need to do in the server to aggregate things, and to split them on the client; along with other less measurable things like code clarity and maintainability, and so forth.

I would say that common pragmatic judgement applies here: if you can make the same work with one request, why making 10 requests ? Do you have a more specific example ?

If you are in doubt, measure.

Comment: My example: I was thinking about an one-page website with all but the first request sent using XHR and instead of requesting all the resources with one XHR each, I'd use just one. So it would rather be 10x less then 10x more requests. Then, however, I learned about http/2 and started wondering whether coding all the image+html+js+css concatenation and cliend-side splitting would be worth it. Seems improbable. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I would say to not bother to concatenate resources that are easily cacheable by the browser such as CSS, JavaScript and image/icon files. Image spriting, domain sharding, resource inlining, etc. are all "tricks" to workaround HTTP/1.1 limitations. Don't use them in HTTP/2.

Comment: If, in your single page web app, you need to make 10 requests to services (that, say, return JSON) to populate the page with data, then those 10 requests will be more efficient when using HTTP/2 than HTTP/1.1. However, consider designing your application in a way that the initial state can be populated with a single request rather than 10, and use specific requests only to update parts of the page in reaction to user input. HTTP/2 will benefit you in simplicity (no workarounds) and in protocol efficiency, but nothing beats a better design/algorithm.

Comment: Except, at least for HTTP/1.x browsers limit the number of in flight requests to the same domain.  6 seems to be a prevalent limit, so 4 of your requests would be delayed until the first 6 started to complete.

If anyone has info on browser rate limiting behaviour and HTTP/2 please share

Comment: Chrome 57 sends a SETTINGS frame with `maxConcurrentStreams=1000` on connection establishment. This means that with HTTP/2 the parallelism for the number of in-flight request goes from 6 for HTTP/1.1 to 1000 for HTTP/2.